# PHP: Passing in an Array of type Object to the constructor?

Tags: php, oop

When Defining a constructor in a class I initially had something like:

```
public function __construct(MyClass $class){ ... }
```

However I wanted to be able to accept an array of MyClasses, how could you define this in your constructor?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not strictly typecasting, but will enforce what you're looking for.

```
public function __construct(array $classes){
        foreach($classes as $inst){
          if(!($inst instanceof ClassName)){
            trigger_error('Array of objects passed to constructor must contain instances of ClassName', E_USER_ERROR);
            }
            //perform actions
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify one type this way.

So, either an object, instance of `MyClass` :

```
public function __construct(MyClass $class){ ... }
```

Or an `array` :

```
public function __construct(array $data){ ... }
```

But you cannot specify your method only accepts an `array` of `MyClass` -- which means you'll have to check by yourself what kind of data are into the array your receive, in the second case.

Comment: or nothing: public function __construct($class){ ... }

Answer (score 0):

Cast $class as an array.

```
public function __construct($class = array()) { }
```

or

```
public function __construct(array $class) { }
```

further:

```
foreach($class as $instance) { 
      if(!$instance instanceof MyClass) { return false; }
}
```